# Extremely long dryer vent line, non efficient dryer

Tags: vent, dryer

my house is older, and my Dryer vent line runs the length of my house, which is approximately 30 feet.  I am constantly sucking water out of my vent line.  My new dryer still takes forever to dry clothes...  I need help! any suggestions?

Comment: I think it's likely the run is too long or obstructed. In addition to being a nuisance, an improperly-vented dryer is a serious fire hazard. @JimmyFix-it's answer below has a link to a very helpful chart. You will need to figure out exactly how long the vent is, how many bends it has, and what it's made of.

Answer (score 4):

Your dryer manufacturer will have specifications for maximum vent line length, including max distances depending on type and size of vent and how many turns.

It is very important that you:
- use rigid rather than flexible line whenever possible
- minimize elbows and turns
- make it as short of a run as you can (never exceed manufacturer's max)

It is not unusual to have a 30' length, but it should be rigid pipe. Check out this [chart](http://www.appliance411.com/faq/dryer-vent-length.shtml).

Comment: +1 for a rigid line much easier to manage and clean.  One piece of advice is to design the 30 foot run in such a way you can open and access for cleaning and vacuuming occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

**Check for any obstructions**

Is there lint stuck in the vent?

-Turn the dryer on and go outside, do you feel the air coming out? Does the flap open?
If not, try and open the flap manually and visually inspect. The flap should open freely, if there is any resistance this could be part of the problem.

-Disconnect the hose attached to the dyer and visually inspect the vent, you can also try sticking your hand inside to see if there is any lint.
If there is, you will need to have the line cleared of any debris, this can be done by using a vacuum system. You can try and DIY by plugging the end of the run and then using a shop vac to try and suck the lint out. If not a professional will be equipped to  handle this.

-There could be a break in the line
If there is a disconnect in the line, you could end up with some serious moisture issues. If you don't have any hot air exhausting from the vent outside and there are no signs of a blockage, this is a strong possibility and will require some minor demo or a professional.

**Another posibility**
30 Feet sounds like a long run, if the line is cleared of debris and the problem is still occurring, if it is at all possible, shorten the run - the shorter the run, the more efficient the dryer will be.

My wife and I moved into an older home and our clothes were still wet after an hour where as in the other home it would be completely dry in less than 45 minutes.

The entire vent was claughed and I ended up replacing the entire run; who ever installed the dryer line used regular ribbed dryer hose and duck tape.